# Possible to edit script during debugging in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm

I have a PHP script that I am debugging in PhpStorm. I'd like to edit lines below the current breakpoint / cursor, then *Continue* or *Step Over* and have the changes reflected immediately. Is that possible? PhpStorm seems to be evaluating using the original code, not the updated one.

Comment: 1) Nope. 2) *"PhpStorm seems to be evaluating using the original code, not the updated one."* just for your information -- PhpStorm does not actually execute your code -- it's done by PHP itself + xdebug which controls/provides debugging. Therefore Q is -- does PHP itself supports such "hot-swap"? 3)The best that I can suggest is to try EAP build -- they now support [interactive debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/#interactive_debug_console)

Comment: This should be an answer, not a comment :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Current versions of PhpStorm do not have such functionality
2. > "PhpStorm seems to be evaluating using the original code, not the updated one."

   Well... PhpStorm does not actually execute your code -- it's done by PHP itself + xdebug which controls/provides debugging.

   Therefore the Question is -- does PHP itself (or debug extension) supports such "hot-swap"? AFAIK -- no.
3. Considering all the above I may only suggest to try [latest EAP builds](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/) of PhpStorm v10 -- they now support **interactive debugging**: [1](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/#interactive_debug_console), [2](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/09/get-an-advantages-of-interactive-console-during-debugging-in-phpstorm-9-5-eap/)